# c# xna: real time 2d Generation. include GPU? use hlsl or bramaha?

Tags: c#, xna, gpu, perlin-noise

Hey i recently finished my world Generation Algorithmus, wich is going to run in real time. The Algorithmus itself takes about 4 sec for 4x my screen (1920x1080). Now i wondered if and how i could use the GPU to generate the simplex noise I am using to split up the work between my CPU and GPU and make it a little faster. So i wondered how to properly include the GPU.
Should i use bramha or hlsl or anything else? And what should i use the GPU for? I have heared that it will be faster when doing many similar operations.

Edit: And how about handling collisions on gpu? (like SAT- Collisions?)

Comment: I doubt that you can do collisions in HLSL with XNA unless its per-pixel particle stuff...  Nvidia has tons of shader examples on their website, just keep in mind that XNA only goes to DirectX 9.0c and doesn't support DirectX 11's compute shaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definitely want to use the GPU.  I would recommend that you use a render to texture step and HLSL.  HLSL is pretty easy to pick up, and I do believe there's a sample for rendering to a texture. (you could do multiple passes too if you pass it back in again)

Here's a good blog on HLSL using XNA 4: http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/xna-4-0-shader-programming-1intro-to-hlsl-ambient-light/

Here's an example of render-to-texture in XNA 4:
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php

Basically speaking, render targets in XNA **are** textures and can be used just like one.